# Unable to display :before and :after if overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a fullscreen website, using javascript to set the height and the width of my sections.

I'd like to have, at the bottom of each section, a diagonal separator.

Now, here's my issue:

In order to display the diagonal divs, i need to have overflow set to auto on the container, but if it is auto, the full website scroll to the right as the diagonal div is bigger than the body.

I need the container to have an overflow:hidden, but still be able to see the diagonal dividers.

You can see what i'm talking about here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emoLpd

If you uncomment out  `//overflow:hidden` from `div.website-section` you will see that the diagonal is not visible anymore.

How can i have the overflow hidden and the diagonal divs displayed at the same time?

Thanks in advance for any help.

*PS: sorry for the tons of code, but i'm developing using less and i pasted the full code.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example, forked from your example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jERvrE

No need to set `overflow:hidden` on the `.website-section` divs. You can simply set `overflow-x: hidden` on the `body` element, which keeps horizontal scrollbars from appearing but leaves vertical scrolling unmodified.

This is the important part:

```
body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think about this simple solution! Again, thanks a lot it works as expected now :)